# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strictTemplates'

Tags: angular, typescript, ivy, tsconfig

Compiling an angular application (v10) fails with this error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: tsconfig.json:14:5 - error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strictTemplates'.

14     "strictTemplates": true,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`strictTemplates` is a parameter for the angular compiler.

In your tsconfig.json: move the parameter inside `angularCompilerOptions`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  ...,
  "strictTemplates": true,
  ...
}
```

Angular >= 9 is necessary.

More info here: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck